# May one be mafsik during hallel at the seder?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, hefsek-interruption, hallel

The Gemarah ([Rosh Hashanah 34b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1353&size=1)) says that pausing during Hallel might invalidate one's recitation. Presumably (though maybe not) talking during Hallel is also problematic.

May one speak during the part of Hallel recited after Birchas Hamazon at the seder?

Comment: Can you indicate why you might think it is prohibited? After all, we do Rochtza, Motzi, Matza, Maror, Korech, Shulchan Orech, Tzafun and Barech in the middle of the Hallel at the Seder. People usually talk during some of those and it certainly is a pause.

Comment: I'll second the first sentence of @DoubleAA's comment. (The "After all" part of his comment may not have occurred to you, but there must be *some* reason you're asking whether it's prohibited.)

Comment: We don't seem to paskin like that Gemara though. http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3a03.htm#9

Comment: @DoubleAA Still, the word "יצא" may have the connotation of _bedieved_.

Comment: If that is your argument you should clarify that in the question, preferably with citations of later authorities than the Rambam as well.

Comment: Hallel at the Seder is without a brachah. I seem to remember having learnt that the prohibition on hefsek is basically only on full Hallel with brachah. Half Hallel (even with brachah where said) is less strict.

Comment: @Epicentre But Hallel at the seder is fully obligatory, unlike Half Hallel (eg. on Rosh Chodesh) which is only a Minhag.