# Why don't we raise the fourth kos during Hallel?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, grapes-wine, hallel

Ta'amei HaMinhagim 544 says that we raise our cup from "Lefichach" to the end of Maggid in light of the Gemara in Erchin (11a): "How do we know that we only say Shirah on wine? As it says, 'The grape said to them....'"

According to this logic, why don't we raise our cups during Hallel toward the end of the Seder? Should the derashah not apply to Hallel also? Why do we limit it to Hallel HaMitzri?

Comment: If we extend it to Hallel, maybe we should have wine whenever we say Hallel in shul-- what are the parameters of Ein Omrin Shirah Ela Al HaYayin?

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot That's certainly part of the question. Why limit it to Hallel HaMitzri?

Comment: Who is "we"? I do hold my cup for all of Hallel.

Comment: @DoubleAA My Haggada also says to hold the 4th cup for all of Hallel.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's so interesting. I've never heard of such a minhag.

Comment: The Chabad minhag is _not_ to hold the fourth for the duration of Hallel. I'm so glad it is - I make a big enough mess already when holding the (overflowing) cup for kiddush on Shabbos and Yontif!

Comment: Are you saying that your minhag is to raise for the first hallel but not the second (or that you know that such a minhag exists)? If so, I will adjust my answer

Comment: @jay That's exactly what I'm saying. I pick up the kos at lefichach and keep holding it until the end of Maggid. The fourth cup, on the other hand, remains on the table until the very end.

Comment: I never understood what the point of filling a cup up just to let it sit there on the table. Either hold it during Hallel and say Hallel on a Kos or if you aren't saying Hallel on a Kos then fill it afterwards when you want to drink it.

Comment: I guess to give chashivus to Hallel, the same way that we do for bentching.

Comment: @DonielF Are you responding to me? I'm not sure what you mean by the same as Bentching. When Bentching on a Kos you hold the cup 1 Tefach off the table (OC 183:4).

Comment: @DoubleAA Right... Well, what about Maggid?

Comment: @Doniel we fill it awkwardly early to make the Doniels ask questions! (Though you could argue that you should hold it for all of maggid too ([זכרהו על היין](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56846/why-in-the-haggadah-do-we-split-up-the-hallel/56852#comment151520_56852) see or samech).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differing customs regarding raising the cup during Hallel. The Beis Yosef (end of 422) seems to take it as a given that the cup is raised. The sefer Seder Haaruch suggests that the reason mentioned in your question is indeed the source for this custom.

On the other hand, the [Aruch Hashulchan (473:23)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=104) writes that 'אצלינו' the custom is to put the cup down immediately after לפיכך, so apparently he doesn't agree regarding the reason of saying shirah on wine. He explains that the reason we raise the cup by וְהִיא שֶעָמְדָה and לפיכך is based on the verse כּוֹס יְשׁוּעוֹת אֶשָּׂא - which can be interpreted homiletically to mean that we raise the cup when we mention salvation. This idea is also found in the commentary of the Rokeach, who also implies that this applies specifically to national salvation.

I think perhaps we can explain your custom by extending this reasoning to cover the first Hallel as well, which prominently features the salvation from Egypt (the commentary attributed to the Rashbam understands even the first psalm as referring to *yetzias mitzrayim*). The second hallel is not about national salvation, but is rather more of a general praise, so we don't raise the cup.

So perhaps those who raise during the first Hallel for the reason mentioned by the Ta'amei HaMinhagim are indeed those who also raise during the second Hallel.

Comment: Bikkurim is also general praise, yet that's exactly where we apply this derasha.

Comment: How do we know *shirah* is said on wine. Why would it matter what type of shirah it is?

Comment: @DonielF When I differentiated between the hallels I wasn't going with the shirah reason. I agree with your premise that if that's the reason it should apply to both hallels regardless of the subject.